# How do I edit the page title in pages created with sites.google.com?

Tags: seo, google, website-promotion

I have created my website in Google Sites. Now I want to update Meta tags to optimize it.

I've figured out how to enter description for the page but I can't figure out how to edit the page title.   How do I do that?

Comment: How did you set the meta description?   Google Sites appears to set the page title based on what you name the page, but I don't see how you set a description.

Answer (score 1):

According to the G Suite Learning Center [documentation](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/sites/get-started/#!/section-1-2), there are three aspects involved to naming your site:

> 1. **Site document name**—Enter a unique name to keep track of your site. The site document name is only visible to you.
> 2. **Site name**—The site name appears in the header and in the web or mobile window title bar after you publish the site. You need to have 2 or more pages in your website for your site name to appear.
> 3. **Page title**—Each page in your site has a title, which appears at the top of the page. The page title also appears in the navigation menu.

Therefore, if you change the **Site Name**, the `<title>` tag should update accordingly.